# C# WPF Get Value from DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a dataGrid with a column `DataGridComboBoxColumn` fill with list.
My ComboBox display my data but I don't know how to get the selected value in C#.

XAML :

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Valideur" 
                        x:Name="cmbBoxGrid"
                        Width="Auto" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding valideur}"
                        ItemsSource="{StaticResource ValideurList}"/>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any `SelectedValuePath`, it looks like you're confusing `SelectedItemBinding` with `SelectedValueBinding`. Which one do you actually need?

Comment: Actually i need the value of this comboBox to update value in database. Like string value = cmbBoxGrid.Text. i'm begginer with WPF

Comment: `SelectedItem` is the data item, selected in `ComboBox`. `SelectedValue` is the value, that could be retrieved from `SelectedItem`, using `SelectedValuePath`. E.g., if `SelectedValuePath` is "Foo.Bar", then selected value is `SelectedItem.Foo.Bar`. At least, you need to replace `SelectedValueBinding` with `SelectedItemBinding`.

Comment: Thanks. Done. And how can i get the value by code ?! that's the problem for me.

Comment: You can get it by reading `valideur` property in your binding source. That's why you're setting binding.

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: No body ?! This Column make me crazy...